# External hard drive with too little power - corrupt data, damage drive, or just not work?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, power

If an external platter-based hard drive has too little power via a USB port, will the result be:

1. Corrupt data?
2. Damage to hard drive?
3. Damage to USB port / motherboard?
4. The drive simply not working?
5. A combination of the above?

Comment: You won't damage the port or motherboard because it won't provide more current than the port is designed to handle.  It takes more current to spin up the drive than to operate it once it's spinning.  So if it spins up, it probably means that the port is providing the power it needs.  If it's real marginal, though, I wouldn't rule out flaky performance, which could mean corrupted data.  If the current is inadequate to spin up, the motor could get very hot, perhaps ruining the drive.  The only way to know for sure is to test it (which could turn out to be "destructive testing").

Comment: If you're referring to the unpowered hub question, I suspect that the connection will just not be recognized if it is trying to negotiate for more current than is available.

Comment: I asked Ali Chen, our resident USB expert, to weigh in.  He added that the drive might power cycle on and off endlessly, depending on the port design.  There are really too many variables to reliably know what will happen in a specific case.  That's why I didn't want to post an answer (and I'm guessing his assessment is similar since he didn't post an answer, either).